# PHP - print namespace constant within a string?

Tags: php, string, constants, representation, string-interpolation

I have the following test code:

```
namespace Test {
    const ONE = 50;

    class A {
        const TWO = 5;

        public function pA($string) {
            return $string;
        }
    }

    $a = new A();
    print $a->pA($a::TWO);
    print "This is a string: {$a->pA($a::TWO)}";
    print "This is a namespace constant: " . ONE;
    print "This is a namespace constant: " . \Test\ONE;
}
```

All of these examples work, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Can I use string composition to represent the constant like in the first two examples? I've tried many combinations like `"${\Test\B}"` or `"${B}"` or `"${\B}"` but, so far, no luck.

Maybe it isn't possible and I'm overdoing it, but anyway... is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work. You can use $variables, functions or object method calls in double quoted string but not constants. Refer to the PHP [string parsing documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing). You'll find many useful examples.

Comment: I was already fearing I would find such answer haha but it's ok. I just wanted to know if it's possible or not and now I know I should compose my strings with the dot notation instead of composing full strings. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this is the answer. However I currently see no reason why the curly syntax `{\Test\ONE}` should not work. Maybe one should consider to file a change request to the PHP dev team.